# why my discord leaderboard is not working ? , It is not even showing error and I have tried everything to make it work

Tags: python, json, dictionary, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases = ['lb'])
async def leaderboard(ctx , x = 0):
    
    await ctx.send('this command is alive but dead for some reason idk')
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["wallet"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)
    total = sorted(total,reverse=True)    
    
    em = discord.Embed(title = f"Top {x} Richest People" , description = "This is decided on the basis of raw money in the bank and wallet",color = discord.Color(0xfa43ee))
    index = 1
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = client.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name = f"{index}. {name}" , value = f"{amt}",  inline = False)
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1
            
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

I don't know why my leaderboard command is not working , if I use `await ctx.send(embed = em)` before the for loop it is sending `top 0 richest people` but it is not sending message after the for loop , so I think that the problem is in the loop

here is the get_bank_data function

```
async def get_bank_data():
    with open('mainbank.json','r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
```

and here is the json file

```
{"555463650358329354": {"wallet": 545, "bank": 7194, "bag": [{"item": "watch", "amount": 0}]}, "886271151729414154": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 0}, "525961784297914378": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 0}, "680988467270123522": {"wallet": 901, "bank": 0}, "725722170206060624": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 507}, "517879304562933780": {"wallet": 137, "bank": 388}, "706831502859698226": {"wallet": 189, "bank": 2124, "bag": [{"item": "watch", "amount": 1}]}, "781446116955914260": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 5511, "bag": [{"item": "watch", "amount": 1}]}, "875681501696643102": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 1664}, "599611694746042380": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 1206}, "786899180240502804": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 104}, "537275315530104832": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 228}, "632848175992012825": {"wallet": 235, "bank": 0}, "704319968183058492": {"wallet": 241, "bank": 0}, "864813571501195315": {"wallet": 0, "bank": 203}}
```

pleaseee helpp

Comment: _What_ is not working?

Comment: it is not showing any output , not sending any message after that for loop

Comment: Is the embed or initial text being sent?

Comment: @SuvenPandey , yes  , but before the for loop

Comment: I cant use the name field in my test but apart from that it seems to be working. Is that the complete data in mainbank.json? I can't think of anything else except maybe try sending user to see if it goes through the whole file.

Comment: Why do you want to send the embed multiple times?

Comment: You might not want to do this: `leader_board[total_amount] = name`. If two people have the same balance you would overwrite the value with second user and display the second user twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not sending any output because it's not breaking up on

```
if index == x:
    break
```

As you are changing `index = 1` and increasing it in the `else` statement

```
index = 0 #start by declaring index = 0
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = client.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name = f"{index+1}. {name}" , value = f"{amt}",  inline = False)# add 1 to index here
        if index == x: #now if index is 0 it'll break the loop and send the message
            break
        else:
            index += 1
```